# Stubborn Folder That Keeps Restoring Itself

Tags: bash, macos, macos-sierra, recycle-bin

I have a folder that every time I delete, it restores itself. I tried everything I can think of - even putting it back, moving it to the trash again, and deleting it permanently. I am on an 11in mid-2012 Macbook Air, running OSX Sierra 10.12.3.

When I click on the trash can in the doc I get this:

[image]

This is what the terminal says:

[image]

Now, this is where it gets really weird. When I run `open .` in the termnal, I get this:

[image]

It's different from the original trash folder! Here is a side by side:

[image]

My first guess is AI system are trying to take over the world, and my laptop is trying to kill me; however, I'm pretty sure that is at least a few years in the future. It's important to note that I am a developer, and I have installed lots of NPM modules, Brew kegs - I think they are called -, Ruby Gems, etc. Perhaps something I installed is causing the issue, but I think it could just as easily be a bug in OSX.

Please save me from the AI...

Answer (score 1):

The Finder presents a *unified view* of all trash folders *across all volumes* in its Trash view; it doesn't *only* show the contents of `~/.Trash` (the differing folder icons in Finder's title bar provide a clue).

Drag your mystery item into a Terminal window to see its full path, which will tell you where it's stored.

---

In your case, the item turned out to be from the *iCloud Drive*'s trash folder, whose underlying local filesystem cache location is:

```
 ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
```

with hidden subfolder `.Trash` containing the iCloud Drive-specific trash.

It's better not to manipulate these automatically managed locations directly, but it's worth trying to use `Finder` in this case (not sure it will work):

- Open `Finder` to the `iCloud Drive` folder.
- If normally hidden subfolder `.Trash` isn't visible, press ⇧⌘. (Shift-Command-Period) to make Finder show all hidden items too.
- Unfortunately, items cannot be *deleted* from this location through Finder, but you can try to *move* your phantom item elsewhere - such as by dragging it to your Desktop or to a non-trash location in your iCloud Drive - to see if that makes it disappear from the Trash. If so, you can then use the shell to `rm -r` the (moved) phantom folder, which bypasses the Trash.

Comment: The path is `/Users/christianjuth/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/.Trash`. I think the issue is the folder seems to be in an iCloud trash folder and every time I delete it iCloud just redownloads it. I still think it is a bug that it restores itself, because iCloud shout be smart enough to know I want it deleted perminatly like normal trash items. Maybe it will dissapear afer 30 days when files perminatly delete themselves.

Comment: There is no `move to trash` option when I left click. I tried using `rm -rf` from the iClound trash folder, but the folder still restores itself. I also download Avast just to confirm I don't have a virus, although the folder is a project I created, so I dont see why it would be. No virus detected, this is definatly an issue Apple overlooked, which seems to be happening more and more often.

Comment: The _permanetly delete_ option only shows up in the aggregated trash folder found in the dock. When I go to `~CloudDocs/.Trash` and control click there is no option to delete the folder. If I click _permanetly delete_ from the aggregated trash the item does get deleted, but iCloud redownloads it a second later.

Comment: @ChristianJuth: Yes, sorry, I should have tried myself. I've updated my answer again, with a different suggestion. You could even try to see what happens if you select `Put Back` from the context menu in the aggregate Trash view - assuming that command is enabled.